# Starting with an empty site in visual studio, how do I define URL Routing?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, routes

I tried to make `public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)` based on examples here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx, however I have to register RouteCollection somewhere, and putting using statements in global.asax doesn't seem to work.  If this is the wrong approach please let me know!  Visual Studio 2010, I think .net 4

Comment: Are you using a ASP.Net MVC project type or WebForms?

Comment: I am starting with an empty web site and building it from scratch.  I am use to doing this in other languages (C++, Golang, Python).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all I needed:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to add a global.asax, in the Application_Start() event, you need to register all your routes.  if its MVC, you can use like this

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("",
        "Default", //RouteName
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL,with parameters
        new  
           {
              controller="yourControllerName", 
              action="yourView"
              ID="ifAnyUrl Parameter Needed"

           }
}
```

then call in Application_Start method

```
   protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            }
```

Edit.  for Asp.net webforms . (.net 4)

you can do like this .

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("yourRouteName", "yourRouteurl as Alias",
                                                   "yourPhysicalAspxFile With properPath");

}
```

in Web.config, you need to make sure that, you have a entry of system.WebServer in configuration section, it should like this.

```
<configuration> 
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This is an empty web site.  If I add public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) then is says it can't find "RouteCollection".   Do I need a "using" statement somewhere?

Comment: I just clicked, "empty web site", which gives no files.  I expect to find the "entry point" for the url, to be where I register the routes, which parses the URL and sends it to a function, which will likely be in default.aspx.cs.  That should do some work and pass data to default.aspx, which will render my final pages.

Comment: you have to add global.asax file. project->Add new item->Global Application Class. under that you paste those codeds.

Comment: Right, that is where I pasted the code, and that is where it says it cannot identify RouteCollection.

Comment: you need to import System.Web.Routing, and add assembly to your project referance.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6971/discussion-between-ravi-and-mvrak)

Comment: ok, so what file does that line go in?  Isn't it "using System.Web.Routing", like all the other import statements.  Please edit your answer to include just the instructions on where to put this import statement, cause what you have up there looks like it is copy pasted from the example I gave...

Comment: i tried to solve your problem, with my expierience. and though you are saying, i'm copied from your link, then why not you try on your own. though its community, people will help, if they know something. ok. anyway you are not clear in your comments.  i tried to cover it all things.

Comment: sorry, i didnt mean to offend, i still have the original question which is just where to put the using statement, thank you for your efforts

Comment: come into discussion, will try tohelp you